# running total using mysql

Tags: php, sql, html

(Ref query and results update below, of a working system, if I hardcode the portfolio)
I am trying to create a running total of a payment balance in one of two ways using mysql (using sub select and using variables), both methods however are not producing the correct results. The first method is closest only failing where dates are the same, although is this method less efficient than using variables.

The report shows dividend payments for a portfolio(s) of stocks in sequence of payment date (pdate), grouped by payment date, portfolio and share (code)

```
SELECT
  d.code                                      AS code,
  p.name                                      AS portfolio,
  d.pdate                                     AS pdate,
  d.dividend                                  AS dividend,
  CEILING(SUM(t.quantity))                    AS quantity,
  CEILING(SUM(t.quantity) * d.dividend / 100) AS payment,

  (
    SELECT CEILING(SUM(din.dividend * tin.quantity) / 100)
    FROM
      transaction tin
      INNER JOIN member min ON (tin.member_id = min.id)
      INNER JOIN dividend din ON (tin.code = din.code)
      INNER JOIN portfolio pin ON (tin.portfolio_id = pin.id)
    WHERE
      (min.id >= '01' AND min.id <= '02')
      AND
      din.pdate <= d.pdate
      AND
      din.pdate >= NOW()
      AND
      pin.name <> 'FDR_JNT'
  ) AS balance
FROM
  transaction t
  INNER JOIN member m ON (m.id = t.member_id)
  INNER JOIN portfolio p ON (p.id = t.portfolio_id)
  INNER JOIN account a ON (a.id = p.account_id)
  INNER JOIN dividend d ON (d.code = t.code)
WHERE
  (m.id >= '01' AND m.id <= '02')
  AND
  d.exchange = t.exchange
  AND
  d.pdate >= NOW()
GROUP BY pdate, portfolio, code
```

Results are shown below, balance on RHS

```
+----------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+----------+
| code     | portfolio     | pdate        | dividend      | quantity     | payment     | balance  |
+----------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+----------+
| BLND     | AJB_SIPP_CO   | 2018-05-05   | 7.52          | 1643         | 124         | 124      |
| AV.      | AJB_SIPP_CO   | 2018-05-17   | 15.88         | 2135         | 340         | 831      |
| AV.      | SFT_DEA_CO    | 2018-05-17   | 15.88         | 2318         | 369         | 831      |
| DLG      | AJB_SIPP_CO   | 2018-05-18   | 9.7           | 2732         | 266         | 1367     |
| DLG      | SFT_DEA_CO    | 2018-05-18   | 9.7           | 2789         | 271         | 1367     |
| SLA      | AJB_SIPP_CO   | 2018-05-23   | 13.35         | 2820         | 377         | 2177     |
| SLA      | SFT_DEA_CO    | 2018-05-23   | 13.35         | 3247         | 434         | 2177     |
| PHP      | AJB_SIPP_CO   | 2018-05-27   | 1.31          | 6947         | 92          | 2268     |
| LLOY     | AJB_SIPP_CO   | 2018-05-29   | 2.05          | 15519        | 319         | 3569     |
| LLOY     | SFT_DEA_CL    | 2018-05-29   | 2.05          | 40011        | 821         | 3569     |
| LLOY     | SFT_ISA_CO    | 2018-05-29   | 2.05          | 7973         | 164         | 3569     |
| FCPT     | AJB_SIPP_CL   | 2018-05-31   | 0.5           | 223          | 2           | 3809     |
+----------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+----------+
```

I have also attempted using a second method using variables as follows

```
SELECT
  d.code                                          AS code,
  p.name                                          AS portfolio,
  d.pdate                                         AS pdate,
  d.dividend                                      AS dividend,
  CEILING(SUM(t.quantity))                        AS quantity,
  CEILING(SUM(t.quantity) * d.dividend / 100)     AS payment,

  (@running_total := @running_total + CEILING(SUM(t.quantity) * d.dividend / 100)) AS balance

FROM
  transaction t
  JOIN (SELECT @running_total := 0) r

  INNER JOIN member m ON (m.id = t.member_id)
  INNER JOIN portfolio p ON (p.id = t.portfolio_id)
  INNER JOIN account a ON (a.id = p.account_id)
  INNER JOIN dividend d ON (d.code = t.code)
WHERE
  (m.id >= '01' AND m.id <= '02')
  AND
  d.exchange = t.exchange
  AND
  d.pdate >= NOW()
GROUP BY
  pdate, portfolio, code
```

Results here

```
+----------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-------------------+
| code     |  portfolio   |    pdate     |    dividend |     quantity |     payment |      balance      |
+----------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-------------------+
| BLND     | AJB_SIPP_CO  | 2018-05-05   | 7.52        | 1643         | 124         | 124               |
| AV.      | AJB_SIPP_CO  | 2018-05-17   | 15.88       | 2135         | 340         | 340               |
| AV.      | SFT_DEA_CO   | 2018-05-17   | 15.88       | 2318         | 369         | 369               |
| DLG      | AJB_SIPP_CO  | 2018-05-18   | 9.7         | 2732         | 266         | 266               |
| DLG      | SFT_DEA_CO   | 2018-05-18   | 9.7         | 2789         | 271         | 271               |
| SLA      | AJB_SIPP_CO  | 2018-05-23   | 13.35       | 2820         | 377         | 377               |
| SLA      | SFT_DEA_CO   | 2018-05-23   | 13.35       | 3247         | 434         | 434               |
| PHP      | AJB_SIPP_CO  | 2018-05-27   | 1.31        | 6947         | 92          | 92                |
| LLOY     | AJB_SIPP_CO  | 2018-05-29   | 2.05        | 15519        | 319         | 319               |
| LLOY     | SFT_DEA_CL   | 2018-05-29   | 2.05        | 40011        |     +----------+--------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

Again this does not produce the desired results

The problem seems to be related to when there are multiple payments on the same date it groups the balance for all values <= row date, if I had a unique field or a sequential count over the rows to avoid a duplicate key of (date, portfolio, code)

Any help on this is much appreciated as I have tried to code this report without success for sometime.

Let me know if you need further information.

Many thanks in advance

Colin

Update if I hardcode the portfolio **SFT_DEA_CO**, the cumulative balance works see below

```
SELECT 
d.code AS code, 
p.name AS portfolio, 
d.pdate AS pdate,
d.dividend AS dividend, 
CEILING(SUM(t.quantity)) AS quantity,
CEILING(SUM(t.quantity) * d.dividend / 100) AS payment, 

(
SELECT 
CEILING(SUM(din.dividend * tin.quantity)/100)
FROM 
transaction tin
INNER JOIN member min ON (tin.member_id = min.id)
INNER JOIN dividend din ON (tin.code = din.code)
INNER JOIN portfolio pin ON (tin.portfolio_id = pin.id)
WHERE
(min.id >= '01' AND min.id <= '02')
AND
din.pdate <= d.pdate
AND
din.pdate >= NOW()
AND
pin.name = 'SFT_DEA_CO'
)
AS balance

FROM 
transaction t
INNER JOIN member m ON (m.id = t.member_id)
INNER JOIN portfolio p ON (p.id = t.portfolio_id)
INNER JOIN account a ON (a.id = p.account_id)
INNER JOIN dividend d ON (d.code = t.code)
WHERE  
(m.id >= '01' AND m.id <= '02')
AND
d.exchange = t.exchange 
AND 
d.pdate >= NOW()
AND
p.name = 'SFT_DEA_CO'
GROUP BY 
pdate, portfolio, code
```

Results are shown below, where the cumulative works, only if Portfolio is hardcoded

```
code    portfolio   pdate   dividend    quantity    payment     balance     
AV. SFT_DEA_CO  2018-05-17  15.88   2318    369 369 
DLG SFT_DEA_CO  2018-05-18  9.7 2789    271 639 
SLA SFT_DEA_CO  2018-05-23  13.35   3247    434 1073    
BP. SFT_DEA_CO  2018-06-23  7.67    446 35  1107    
VUKE    SFT_DEA_CO  2018-07-05  44.255  899 398 1505    
GSK SFT_DEA_CO  2018-07-13  19  2242    426 1931    
MKS SFT_DEA_CO  2018-07-14  11.9    4223    503 2433    
VOD SFT_DEA_CO  2018-08-04  8.8 12053   1061    3494    
BT.A    SFT_DEA_CO  2018-09-04  10.55   8802    929 4422    
DLG SFT_DEA_CO  2018-09-08  6.8 2789    190 4612    
BP. SFT_DEA_CO  2018-09-22  7.67    446 35  5386    
SSE SFT_DEA_CO  2018-09-22  63.9    1158    740 5386    
VUKE    SFT_DEA_CO  2018-10-04  36.046  899 325 5710    
GSK SFT_DEA_CO  2018-10-12  19  2242    426 6136
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this example will give you the necessary structure...
I built a single table called 'test' that contains the few columns you have referenced.  The query example has 2 separate row identification variables so you can confirm the order the rows were processed.

The inner subquery has the row_num counter that registers the order the rows are walked during the aggregation process and the outer query has the row_n counter that registers the new order that you are attempting to use to display the data.

Hope this helps.

The query is below....

```
    select
     @row_n := @row_n + 1 as row_n,
     row_num,
     code,
     portfolio,
     pdate,
     dividend,
     quantity,
     payment,
     balance
     from ( select
     @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_num,
     code,
     portfolio,
     pdate,
     dividend,
     quantity,
     ceiling(dividend*quantity/100) as payment,
     @balance := ceiling(dividend*quantity/100) + if (@prev_pfl = portfolio,@balance,0) as balance,
     @prev_pfl := portfolio as prev_portfolio
    from test
    cross join
    ( select @row_num := 0, @balance := 0, @prev_pfl := '' ) as InitVarsAlias 
    order by portfolio, pdate,code) as SubQueryAlias
    cross join 
    (select @row_n := 0 ) as InitVarsAlias2 
    order by pdate,portfolio,code,row_num;
```

and the result is below

```
    row_n   row_num     code    portfolio       pdate       dividend    quantity    payment     balance
    1       2           BLND    AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-05  7.52        1643        124         124
    2       3           BLND    AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-05  7.52        1643        124         248
    3       4           AV.     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-17  15.88       2135        340         588
    4       18          AV.     SFT_DEA_CO      2018-05-17  15.88       2318        369         369
    5       5           DLG     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-18  9.70        2732        266         854
    6       19          DLG     SFT_DEA_CO      2018-05-18  9.70        2789        271         640
    7       6           SLA     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-23  13.35       2820        377         1231
    8       20          SLA     SFT_DEA_CO      2018-05-23  13.35       3247        434         1074
    9       7           PHP     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-27  1.31        6947        92          1323
    10      8           LLOY    AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-29  2.05        15519       319         1642
    11      15          LLOY    SFT_DEA_CL      2018-05-29  2.05        40011       821         821
    12      24          LLOY    SFT_ISA_CO      2018-05-29  2.05        7973        164         164
    13      1           FCPT    AJB_SIPP_CL     2018-05-31  0.50        223         2           2
    14      9           FCPT    AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-31  0.50        5837        30          1672
    15      10          RLSEB   AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-31  1.80        5021        91          1763
    16      22          FCPT    SFT_ISA_CL      2018-05-31  0.50        3609        19          19
    17      23          RLSEB   SFT_ISA_CL      2018-05-31  1.80        2100        38          57
    18      25          FCPT    SFT_ISA_CO      2018-05-31  0.50        5136        26          190
    19      26          RLSEB   SFT_ISA_CO      2018-05-31  1.80        2100        38          228
    20      11          LGEN    AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-06-08  10.35       3923        407         2170
    21      16          LGEN    SFT_DEA_CL      2018-06-08  10.35       10652       1103        1924
    22      12          BP.     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-06-23  7.67        2130        164         2334
    23      13          RDSB    AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-06-23  35.02       436         153         2487
    24      17          RDSB    SFT_DEA_CL      2018-06-23  35.02       1292        453         2377
    25      21          BP.     SFT_DEA_CO      2018-06-23  7.67        446         35          1109
    26      14          CNA     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-06-29  8.40        7512        632         3119
```

If you want to recreate my test exactly here is the table schema I used in my test.

```
    CREATE TABLE `test` (
      `code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `portfolio` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
      `pdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `dividend` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
      `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `payment` double(12,2) DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and here is the code to populate it...

```
    LOCK TABLES `test` WRITE;
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `test` DISABLE KEYS */;
    INSERT INTO `test` VALUES 
    ('BLND','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-05-05',7.52,1643,124.00),
    ('BLND','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-05-05',7.52,1643,124.00),
    ('AV.','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-05-17',15.88,2135,340.00),
    ('AV.','SFT_DEA_CO','2018-05-17',15.88,2318,369.00),
    ('DLG','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-05-18',9.70,2732,266.00),
    ('DLG','SFT_DEA_CO','2018-05-18',9.70,2789,271.00),
    ('SLA','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-05-23',13.35,2820,377.00),
    ('SLA','SFT_DEA_CO','2018-05-23',13.35,3247,434.00),
    ('PHP','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-05-27',1.31,6947,92.00),
    ('LLOY','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-05-29',2.05,15519,319.00),
    ('LLOY','SFT_DEA_CL','2018-05-29',2.05,40011,821.00),
    ('LLOY','SFT_ISA_CO','2018-05-29',2.05,7973,164.00),
    ('FCPT','AJB_SIPP_CL','2018-05-31',0.50,223,2.00),
    ('FCPT','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-05-31',0.50,5837,30.00),
    ('RLSEB','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-05-31',1.80,5021,91.00),
    ('FCPT','SFT_ISA_CL','2018-05-31',0.50,3609,19.00),
    ('RLSEB','SFT_ISA_CL','2018-05-31',1.80,2100,38.00),
    ('FCPT','SFT_ISA_CO','2018-05-31',0.50,5136,26.00),
    ('RLSEB','SFT_ISA_CO','2018-05-31',1.80,2100,38.00),
    ('LGEN','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-06-08',10.35,3923,407.00),
    ('LGEN','SFT_DEA_CL','2018-06-08',10.35,10652,1103.00),
    ('BP.','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-06-23',7.67,2130,164.00),
    ('RDSB','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-06-23',35.02,436,153.00),
    ('RDSB','SFT_DEA_CL','2018-06-23',35.02,1292,453.00),
    ('BP.','SFT_DEA_CO','2018-06-23',7.67,446,35.00),
    ('CNA','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-06-29',8.40,7512,632.00);
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `test` ENABLE KEYS */;
    UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Then just run the query listed at the start.

-- done --

based on the above example I think your query would be more closely approximated by the following.

Note: I included the inner query row_num field in the result but it is not required.

```
    SELECT 
     @row_n := @row_n + 1 as row_n,
     row_num,
     code,
     portfolio,
     pdate,
     dividend,
     quantity,
     payment,
     balance 
    from ( SELECT 
     @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_num,
     din.code as code,
     pin.name as portfolio,
     din.pdate as pdate,
     din.dividend as dividend
     ceiling(sum(tin.quantity)) as quantity,
     ceiling(sum(din.dividend * tin.quantity)/100) as payment,
     ceiling(sum(din.dividend * tin.quantity)/100) + if(@prev_pfl = pin.name,@balance,0) as balance,
     @prev_pfl := pin.name 
    FROM 
    transaction tin
    INNER JOIN member min ON (tin.member_id = min.id)
    INNER JOIN dividend din ON (tin.code = din.code)
    INNER JOIN portfolio pin ON (tin.portfolio_id = pin.id)
    cross join
    ( select @row_num := 0, @balance := 0, @prev_pfl := '' ) as InitVarsAlias 
    WHERE
    (min.id >= '01' AND min.id = NOW()
    ORDER BY pin.name,din.pdate,din.code ) AS SubQueryAlias
    cross join
    (select @row_n := 0 ) as InitVarsAlias2 
    order by pdate,portfolio,code,row_num;
```

Comment: Hi webmite, many thanks for your help, I will try and integrate your solution into my system and get back to you with the results, it will be much later today due to meetings etc. Cheers Colin

Comment: Hi webmite I have included my code at end of question, the only change to your code was to use GROUP BY pdate, portfolio, code instead of ORDER BY due to SUM in expression and pdate is 1st group sort, thanks Colin

Comment: I should have said in the comment, the @balance variable is being reset to zero on each row so cumulative not being evaluated, balance simply equals payment, probably an easy error someone can spot for me thanks Colin

Comment: Hi Colin  ... for this process to work you must use the 'order by' clause not the 'group by'   If you want to verify just run the sub-query on its own and do the incremental math.  The outer query simply changes the order of the results.

Comment: Hi Webmite can you paste the database structure and/or data of your test so I can exactly replicate your test. Many Thanks Colin

Comment: ok, I have added the table creation sql and the insert statements to populate the table above.  If you have further questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi webmite, I have replicated your test code/results which is great, how easy is it to sum(quantity) group by (portfolio, code) in light of your previous comment (must use order by) e.g. BLND would have 1643 + 1643 =3286 outputting one line per code per portfolio etc.  Is there another way to achieve the same result using ORDER BY and not GROUP BY Many Thanks Colin

Comment: you would simply substitute 'sum(quantity) as quantity' for the original field and sum(quantity) in place of quantity in all other instances of the inner query.  That would give you the modified result you are asking for.  It is not however applicable to the original question so I can't give more detail here.

Comment: sorry webmite but I have tried your suggestion, with no luck, do you want me to post a new question, regarding this issue, or can you paste the changes to your test code as I must have missed something ? I can do it by writing an intermediate holdings file but it would be better if I could do it on the fly many thanks Colin

Comment: Hi Colin. I was incorrect in my earlier statement.  My apologies. The issue with summing the quantity by date requires that you assume that the dividend will remain fixed for all entries on a specific date, for any specific portfolio, date, and code.  Is that expected and acceptable to you?

Comment: If you post a new question with the added critieria and post a link in the comments here I do have the necessary sub-query that I can provide.

Comment: Hi webmite, no problems I am very grateful for the help, I have added another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222313/mysql-running-total-of-payments-grouping-by-a-column-share-code as suggested I look forward to hearing from you. Sorry for delay Thanks Colin