# mysql running total of payments grouping by a column, share code

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a running total of payments for each portfolio of stocks/shares, where there are multiple stock purchase transactions for a given stock and portfolio, I need to group the stock into a single line of stock by grouping the quantity and payment for that line.

Table Schema and data below and query and results of query follow

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `portfolio` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dividend` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment` double(12,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

LOCK TABLES `test` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `test` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES 
('BLND','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-05-05',7.52,1643,124.00),
('BLND','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-05-05',7.52,1643,124.00),
('AV.','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-05-17',15.88,2135,340.00),
('AV.','SFT_DEA_CO','2018-05-17',15.88,2318,369.00),
('DLG','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-05-18',9.70,2732,266.00),
('DLG','SFT_DEA_CO','2018-05-18',9.70,2789,271.00),
('SLA','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-05-23',13.35,2820,377.00),
('SLA','SFT_DEA_CO','2018-05-23',13.35,3247,434.00),
('PHP','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-05-27',1.31,6947,92.00),
('LLOY','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-05-29',2.05,15519,319.00),
('LLOY','SFT_DEA_CL','2018-05-29',2.05,40011,821.00),
('LLOY','SFT_ISA_CO','2018-05-29',2.05,7973,164.00),
('FCPT','AJB_SIPP_CL','2018-05-31',0.50,223,2.00),
('FCPT','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-05-31',0.50,5837,30.00),
('RLSEB','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-05-31',1.80,5021,91.00),
('FCPT','SFT_ISA_CL','2018-05-31',0.50,3609,19.00),
('RLSEB','SFT_ISA_CL','2018-05-31',1.80,2100,38.00),
('FCPT','SFT_ISA_CO','2018-05-31',0.50,5136,26.00),
('RLSEB','SFT_ISA_CO','2018-05-31',1.80,2100,38.00),
('LGEN','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-06-08',10.35,3923,407.00),
('LGEN','SFT_DEA_CL','2018-06-08',10.35,10652,1103.00),
('BP.','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-06-23',7.67,2130,164.00),
('RDSB','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-06-23',35.02,436,153.00),
('RDSB','SFT_DEA_CL','2018-06-23',35.02,1292,453.00),
('BP.','SFT_DEA_CO','2018-06-23',7.67,446,35.00),
('CNA','AJB_SIPP_CO','2018-06-29',8.40,7512,632.00);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `test` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

query shown below followed by results

```
select
 @row_n := @row_n + 1 as row_n,
 row_num,
 code,
 portfolio,
 pdate,
 dividend,
 quantity,
 payment,
 balance
 from ( select
 @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_num,
 code,
 portfolio,
 pdate,
 dividend,
 quantity,
 ceiling(dividend*quantity/100) as payment,
 @balance := ceiling(dividend*quantity/100) + if (@prev_pfl = portfolio,@balance,0) as balance,
 @prev_pfl := portfolio as prev_portfolio
from test
cross join
( select @row_num := 0, @balance := 0, @prev_pfl := '' ) as InitVarsAlias 
order by portfolio, pdate,code) as SubQueryAlias
cross join 
(select @row_n := 0 ) as InitVarsAlias2 
order by pdate,portfolio,code,row_num;
```

results of query, followed by desired results

```
row_n   row_num     code    portfolio       pdate       dividend    quantity    payment     balance
1       2           BLND    AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-05  7.52        1643        124         124
2       3           BLND    AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-05  7.52        1643        124         248
3       4           AV.     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-17  15.88       2135        340         588
4       18          AV.     SFT_DEA_CO      2018-05-17  15.88       2318        369         369
5       5           DLG     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-18  9.70        2732        266         854
6       19          DLG     SFT_DEA_CO      2018-05-18  9.70        2789        271         640
7       6           SLA     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-23  13.35       2820        377         1231
8       20          SLA     SFT_DEA_CO      2018-05-23  13.35       3247        434         1074
9       7           PHP     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-27  1.31        6947        92          1323
10      8           LLOY    AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-29  2.05        15519       319         1642
11      15          LLOY    SFT_DEA_CL      2018-05-29  2.05        40011       821         821
12      24          LLOY    SFT_ISA_CO      2018-05-29  2.05        7973        164         164
13      1           FCPT    AJB_SIPP_CL     2018-05-31  0.50        223         2           2
14      9           FCPT    AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-31  0.50        5837        30          1672
15      10          RLSEB   AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-31  1.80        5021        91          1763
16      22          FCPT    SFT_ISA_CL      2018-05-31  0.50        3609        19          19
17      23          RLSEB   SFT_ISA_CL      2018-05-31  1.80        2100        38          57
18      25          FCPT    SFT_ISA_CO      2018-05-31  0.50        5136        26          190
19      26          RLSEB   SFT_ISA_CO      2018-05-31  1.80        2100        38          228
20      11          LGEN    AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-06-08  10.35       3923        407         2170
21      16          LGEN    SFT_DEA_CL      2018-06-08  10.35       10652       1103        1924
22      12          BP.     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-06-23  7.67        2130        164         2334
23      13          RDSB    AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-06-23  35.02       436         153         2487
24      17          RDSB    SFT_DEA_CL      2018-06-23  35.02       1292        453         2377
25      21          BP.     SFT_DEA_CO      2018-06-23  7.67        446         35          1109
26      14          CNA     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-06-29  8.40        7512        632         3119
```

Desired results, are as above except BLND being the only share having more than one transaction is grouped/summated as follows for quantity and payment (2 lines is summated to a single line)

```
row_n   row_num     code    portfolio       pdate       dividend    quantity    payment     balance
1       2           BLND    AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-05  7.52        3286        248         248
2       4           AV.     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-17  15.88       2135        340         588
3       18          AV.     SFT_DEA_CO      2018-05-17  15.88       2318        369         369
4       5           DLG     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-18  9.70        2732        266         854
5       19          DLG     SFT_DEA_CO      2018-05-18  9.70        2789        271         640
6       6           SLA     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-23  13.35       2820        377         1231
7       20          SLA     SFT_DEA_CO      2018-05-23  13.35       3247        434         1074
```

etc ...

Many Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how to achieve this result.

Colin

Comment: Note that money is never double. It's why decimal was invented

Comment: good point , Thanks Colin

Comment: Also, if you don't have a unique key (some would say 'primary'), then you don't really have a table.

Comment: Hi Strawberry, good advice all my tables have a primary key, id but as this just a test I was just trying to simplify the problem to its bare essentials to replicate the issue. Do you have any ideas how to group the results by code, portfolio and maintain the running total of balance by portfolio, Thanks Colin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your existing query with another sub-query as follows.

```
select
     @row_n := @row_n + 1 as row_n,
     row_num,
     code,
     portfolio,
     pdate,
     dividend,
     quantity,
     payment,
     balance
     from ( select
     @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_num,
     code,
     portfolio,
     pdate,
     dividend,
     quantity,
     ceiling(dividend*quantity/100) as payment,
     @balance := ceiling(dividend*quantity/100) + if (@prev_pfl = portfolio,@balance,0) as balance,
     @prev_pfl := portfolio as prev_portfolio
    from ( select
     code,
     portfolio,
     pdate,
     dividend,
     sum(quantity) as quantity 
    from test
    group by portfolio, pdate,code, dividend
    order by portfolio, pdate,code, dividend ) as SubQueryAlias1
    cross join
    ( select @row_num := 0, @balance := 0, @prev_pfl := '' ) as InitVarsAlias1 
    order by portfolio, pdate,code) as SubQueryAlias2
    cross join 
    (select @row_n := 0 ) as InitVarsAlias2 
    order by pdate,portfolio,code,row_num;
```

and it will provide you with the appropriate output as you requested.

```
row_n   row_num     code    portfolio       pdate       dividend    quantity    payment     balance
1       2           BLND    AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-05  7.52        3286        248         248
2       3           AV.     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-17  15.88       2135        340         588
3       17          AV.     SFT_DEA_CO      2018-05-17  15.88       2318        369         369
4       4           DLG     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-18  9.70        2732        266         854
5       18          DLG     SFT_DEA_CO      2018-05-18  9.70        2789        271         640
6       5           SLA     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-23  13.35       2820        377         1231
7       19          SLA     SFT_DEA_CO      2018-05-23  13.35       3247        434         1074
8       6           PHP     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-27  1.31        6947        92          1323
9       7           LLOY    AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-29  2.05        15519       319         1642
10      14          LLOY    SFT_DEA_CL      2018-05-29  2.05        40011       821         821
11      23          LLOY    SFT_ISA_CO      2018-05-29  2.05        7973        164         164
12      1           FCPT    AJB_SIPP_CL     2018-05-31  0.50        223         2           2
13      8           FCPT    AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-31  0.50        5837        30          1672
14      9           RLSEB   AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-05-31  1.80        5021        91          1763
15      21          FCPT    SFT_ISA_CL      2018-05-31  0.50        3609        19          19
16      22          RLSEB   SFT_ISA_CL      2018-05-31  1.80        2100        38          57
17      24          FCPT    SFT_ISA_CO      2018-05-31  0.50        5136        26          190
18      25          RLSEB   SFT_ISA_CO      2018-05-31  1.80        2100        38          228
19      10          LGEN    AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-06-08  10.35       3923        407         2170
20      15          LGEN    SFT_DEA_CL      2018-06-08  10.35       10652       1103        1924
21      11          BP.     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-06-23  7.67        2130        164         2334
22      12          RDSB    AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-06-23  35.02       436         153         2487
23      16          RDSB    SFT_DEA_CL      2018-06-23  35.02       1292        453         2377
24      20          BP.     SFT_DEA_CO      2018-06-23  7.67        446         35          1109
25      13          CNA     AJB_SIPP_CO     2018-06-29  8.40        7512        632         311
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi webmite just replicated your code and all works, I am very pleased with the results, just what I needed, have a good day and many thanks for all your help. regards Colin

Comment: Thanks Colin.  It was a good question.  Clear enough in terms of what you were looking for and you gave a sample of data to work with.

Comment: Please remember to mark the question as answered.  No worries!